# remove <style> from div class with jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want erase a inline CSS `<style>` element in a `<div>` element.  This `<style>` element is output from a JavaScript file.

This is the document:

```
<div id="rmid" class="rm">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/file.js"></script>
</div>
```

Loading this JavaScript file creates additional elements *(editor's note: presumably via document.write())* , resulting in HTML markup like the following example:

```
<div id="rmid" class="rm">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/file.js"></script>
    <style> ............. </style>
    various content
</div>
```

How can I  remove this when loading the page ?

Comment: @SURTLER77 If your `file.js` is using `document.write()` to produce the element, then I recommend changing it and not doing that. Instead define a function that the page can call when, and where, it wants new elements created in the DOM.

Comment: unfortunately the js file not owned by me, I can only read but not edit it, it would be in the form of getresponse

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery, 
 you could use

```
$(document).ready( function() { $( '#rmid > style' ).remove(); } );
```

If you plan to not use jQuery, the things changes a little bit:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("rmid");
parent.querySelector("style").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: ...as I see @SURTLER77 suggested the same solution in the meanwhile. Sorry mate.

Comment: thanks for response, but not work, i don't think the problem is your code, i check a page source of page after load but if i try to search the tag  not i see, the code posted is on a popup, this popup start from this code "jQuery('#1tg_reservation').on( 'click', function() {....", so i see the code in html page and if use  "ispection element" of google chrome, but if try to show page souce not i see, why ?

Comment: my site use this theme http://themes.themegoods2.com/grandrestaurant/, on top right you can show a button reservation , in the popup(class "reservation_form_wrapper") i load the code posted

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function `<body onload="removeStyles()"` This will select all the styles in your above mentioned div with #id = id.

```
function removeStyles(){
    var sty = document.querySelectorAll('div#id style');
    for(var i=0; i<sty.length; i++){
        sty.item(i).remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, but not work, i don't think the problem is your code, i check a page source of page after load but if i try to search the tag  not i see, the code posted is on a popup, this popup start from this code "jQuery('#1tg_reservation').on( 'click', function() {....", so i see the code in html page and if use  "ispection element" of google chrome, but if try to show page souce not i see, why ?